# How to segue to a view managed by a tab bar controller and pass data

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a login view that takes a username and password and grabs an webpage string. I want to then pass this information to the next view where itll load the html string.  The problem is that the second view is managed by a tab bar controller (the one that was generated by default tab bar template in xcode). However, when i segue into it I lose the tab bar controller. My segue goes from the login view controller directly to the second view. I tried directing it to the tab bar controller itself but I wasn't able to pass the data from the login view to the first view. Any tips or workarounds for this?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSchedule"]){
        SocialSchedulerFirstViewController *scheduleController = (SocialSchedulerFirstViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSString *webPageCode = htmlString;
        scheduleController.htmlString = webPageCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove segue login to tabbar controller, you need to do it programatically

**Set your tabBarcontroller in storyboard as initial controller**

**Inside AppDelegate.m**

```
if (authenticatedUser)
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];


}
else
{
       UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

        UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
}
```

**Inside LoginController**

```
- (IBAction)actionLogin:(id)sender {


AppDelegate *appDelegateTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

appDelegateTemp.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the segue to go from your login view controller directly to tab bar controller. You had problem with passing data because you try to pass it to tab bar,I guess, but you should get reference to your view controller first. Try this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSchedule"]){
        UITabBarController *tabar=(UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        SocialSchedulerFirstViewController *scheduleController = (SocialSchedulerFirstViewController *)[tabar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];;
        NSString *webPageCode = htmlString;
        scheduleController.htmlString = webPageCode;
    }
}
```

It will works if your SocialSchedulerFirstViewController is first tab of tab bar controller.